# Finding old answers that don't garner upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, answers

I was gone for about a year and now I'm back. I noticed that I gained a steady trickle of upvotes while I was gone from a few answers that I had given.

I would like to be able to find a list of old answers that don't garner upvotes. My rationale is that they're not useful and so should be improved or deleted if there is already an answer that has everything that I would add. Clearly this doesn't apply to quick technical questions that no one but the asker is likely to be interested in anyways. I'm thinking of my answers to the sort of questions that can elicit general answers that explain some language feature.

I don't know how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to write a [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to find answers you own which have no reported up votes within a certain period.

Seemed like a fun task, so assuming I didn't make any glaring mistakes, here's a list of your [answers which haven't received up votes in the last 365 days and have score < 5](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66094?MaxScore=5&IdleDays=365&UserId=376728).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you kindly. Is this code T-sql or an in-house dialect?

Comment: Sure thing! It's just T-SQL (though the `##parameters##` are a Data Explorer thing).

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could parameterize stuff..

Comment: What the... you can have default values for parameters? This changes everything. Also the documentation is terrible.

Comment: @lunboks [Yep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108909/150235)! Hm, that's a good point. There's a lot of new functionality that should recorded somewhere other than on random Meta posts...I'll make a note (and anyone who wants to help should feel free)!

Answer (score 2):

You can view [your answers in your profile sorted by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376728/aaronasterling?tab=answers&sort=votes), go to the last page to see the lowest scoring, that should provide the list you're after.

If you want more context, you can do so similarly through a search of `user:376728 is:answer` sorted by votes, and again [going to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=9&tab=votes&q=user:376728%20is:answer).