# Data explorer query values in cookies

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

My userid still isn't automatically populated in the `##UserId##` field in data explorer (I've tried updating my avatar etc), so it would be handy if my userid was stored in a cookie and populated automatically.

But it got me thinking, why aren't *all* query variables saved as cookies and automatically populated into fields?

Does this sound like a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

> My userid still isn't automatically populated in the `##UserId##` field

Yeah, the values for `EmailHash` have been removed for privacy reasons, and this is a prerequisite for that code to work. I've been meaning to make some adjustments to address this but have been a bit tied up; hopefully it's something I can get to sometime this week, if not later this evening.

To your request though, there's no guarantee that parameters that have similar names are used for similar purposes*, so I'm not sure that there's a lot of benefit to this. I can see some use cases where it *might* make sense, but doing this across the board doesn't seem that useful to me.

Somewhat tangental to your concern, but you can [set default values](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108899/can-i-set-default-values-for-data-explorer-query-parameters) for query parameters, which can be helpful in some cases.

<sub>*obviously that assumption was being made with the `UserId` field, but that seemed safe since the behaviour was documented</sub>